# Multiplicar un alias con un campo en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta y necesito multiplicar `SI_Dif * m.SI_Costo_Promedio` pero me dice que  `SI_Dif` no es valido.

```
SELECT t.SI_Articulo,
m.SI_Descripcion, 
t.SI_UM, 
(CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END) AS SI_OV, 
t.SI_Ubicacion, 
t.SI_Existencia, 
c.SI_Cantidad, 
c.SI_Cantidad - t.SI_Existencia AS SI_Dif ,
SI_Dif * m.SI_Costo_Promedio AS SI_Dif2
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m ON m.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
LEFT JOIN SI_Conteo c ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En ese SELECT SI_Dif no existe.

Tienes que hacer

```
(c.SI_Cantidad - t.SI_Existencia) * m.SI_Costo_Promedio AS SI_Dif2
```

Asi:

```
SELECT t.SI_Articulo,
m.SI_Descripcion, 
t.SI_UM, 
(CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END) AS SI_OV, 
t.SI_Ubicacion, 
t.SI_Existencia, 
c.SI_Cantidad, 
c.SI_Cantidad - t.SI_Existencia AS SI_Dif ,
(c.SI_Cantidad - t.SI_Existencia) * m.SI_Costo_Promedio AS SI_Dif2
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m ON m.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
LEFT JOIN SI_Conteo c ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo
```

Comment: esta en lo correcto, en el orden de ejecución de la sentencia de SQL, los alias que están el SELECT son invisibles para el mismo, por lo que debes usar el nombre propio de la columna. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Usa los campos originales para el cálculo:

```
...(c.SI_Cantidad - t.SI_Existencias)*m.SI_Costo_Promedio AS SI_Dif2...
```

El otro campo no existe hasta realizar la query.